# Missing "boost_python38-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_76.lib" in VS 2019

Tags: boost

Trying to compile a Boost Python module. But got missing lib file. Is this boost_python38 (using Python 3.8) another static lib needs to be built? And how to build this lib? There is no such lib under /stage/libs folder.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/python/doc/html/building/installing_boost_python_on_your_.html

Comment: How did you setup boost originally? Did you download the binaries pre-built, or did you build it from source?

Comment: I used "boosttrap.bat" then "b2" to build. Looks like I need to build it again from John's link: If you need a regular installation of the Boost.Python library binaries on your system, the Boost Getting Started Guide will walk you through the steps of creating one. If building binaries from source, you might want to supply the --with-python argument to bjam (or the --with-libraries=python argument to configure), so only the Boost.Python binary will be built, rather than all the Boost binaries.

Comment: Did that work? If so, you can answer your own question.

Comment: No, following that link you provided didn't work. The link needs to be updated because b2 doesn't have the option shown in the link. I tried "b2 --with-python". The build kicked off by showing only Python is building. But it quickly said "failed" without any other message. Tried a few times still failed. The missing lib was not generated.

Comment: What boost source version do you have downloaded? 1.76?

Comment: right, Boost 1.76 on Windows 10 with VS2019

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "b2 --with-python" didn't see where pyconfig.h is. So needed to specify the header file like this:

```
b2 --with-python --includedir=<where_the_pyconfig_h_file_is>
```

If installed Python from Anaconda, then need to point to the right location and right version of Python. After that, /stage/lib folder shows the right lib is generated.